# How to send a transaction in private tangle Hornet of IOTA?

Tags: blockchain

I have deployed an IOTA tangle network on Hornet and it is running successfully on http://localhost:8081/. How do I send a transaction to it?

Are there any steps or could you please share any documents/tutorials to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given swagger docs can be used to connect to Hornet running on localhost.

https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rufsam/protocol-rfcs/master/text/0026-rest-api/rest-api.yaml

Answer (score 0):

you can use a iota.rs which is an official, general-purpose IOTA client library in Rust for interaction with the IOTA network (Tangle). There are serval examples in its github(https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs).